# Running a Qt event loop at the R prompt

Tags: python, r, pyqt

I'm trying to create a Qt application that can communicate with R via PyQt and the rPython package and remain responsive while the R prompt is live.

Here's a minimal PyQt4 script that creates a button in a window that prints "clicked" when you click it.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys

class Ui_simple(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Test")
        Dialog.resize(200,200)
        self.pushButton = QPushButton(Dialog)
        QObject.connect(self.pushButton, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.clicked)

    def clicked(self):
        print "Clicked"

class main(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = QApplication([])
        self.Dialog = QDialog()
        self.ui = Ui_simple()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.Dialog)    
        self.Dialog.show()
```

When run from the Python prompt, the application becomes active when the `QDialog` object is created and shown. The python prompt returns. I can then `exec_` the application object, and I get the prompt back when I quit the dialog:

```
>>> import simple
>>> a = simple.main()
>>> Clicked [python prompt is back now, I'm clicking the button]
Clicked
>>> a.app.exec_()
Clicked
```

This behaviour - of being interactive while also waiting for Python text prompt input - is because PyQt4 installs an [input hook](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/python_shell.html#using-pyqt4-from-the-python-shell) that waits for keyboard input and processes events.

What I want to do is have this same behaviour with Qt dialogs called from R via the rPython package. The following displays the dialog but it does not appear until the `exec_` call, and the R prompt does not return until the application is exited by quitting the dialog window:

```
> require(rPython)
Loading required package: rPython
Loading required package: RJSONIO
> python.load("simple.py")
> python.exec("a = main()")     # nothing happens
> python.exec("a.app.exec_()") # dialog appears, R blocked
Clicked
Clicked   # click the buttons
Clicked
    0    # kill window now
> # back to R prompt
```

A solution to my problem would involve the dialog appearing when running `a=main()` and the R prompt reappearing at that point too.

There are some Qt-based R packages that appear to create dialogs that remain interactive when the R prompt is active, but they are mostly in C and I'm not sure if that make a big difference. See [qtutils](https://github.com/cran/qtutils) for example.

There is some event loop handling in [qtbase](https://github.com/cran/qtbase/blob/ea7c6e1fc2b31ceeeee7c6b223e0157f1be46325/src/EventLoop.cpp#L10) but I'm not sure if something like that is possible for Qt apps called from `rPython`. All ideas welcome.